# Shorter way of this NumPy list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy

Is there a simpler and faster way of doing this?

```
maxr, maxc = im_out.shape[:2]

for col in range(maxc):
    for row in range(maxr):
        if im_gray[row,col,0] != 255 and im_gray[row,col,1] != 255 and im_gray[row,col,2] != 255:
            im_out[row, col] = im_gray[row, col]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of this should do the trick:

```
# I think it's axis 2, might have to play around there
mask = (im_gray != 255).all(axis=2)
im_out[mask] = im_gray[mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mask:

```
mask = (im_gray[..., 0] != 255) & (im_gray[..., 1] != 255) & (im_gray[..., 2] != 255)

im_out[mask] = im_gray[mask]
```

The above vectorization finds a mask where the condition is satisfied for all the channels.